# MongoDB URL in MeteorD

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker, docker-toolbox

I am trying to use Docker for meteor application.
I am following this [Git Hub Instructions](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord)
I've build my docker image successfully (i think)

> $ docker build -t thismustbedocker/meteorappgit . Sending build
>   context to Docker daemon 125.9 MB Step 1 : FROM
>   meteorhacks/meteord:onbuild
>
> ## Executing 2 build triggers... Step 1 : COPY ./ /app Step 1 : RUN bash $METEORD_DIR/on_build.sh  ---> Running in eb6f7a698dbf
>
> Downloading Meteor distribution
>
> Meteor 1.3.2.4 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
>   Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your
>   convenience.
>
> To get started fast:
>
> $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app   $ cd ~/my_cool_app   $ meteor
>
> Or see the docs at:
>
> docs.meteor.com
>
> npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important
>   features, npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the
>   primary npm npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at
>   least npm@2, if not the npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To
>   upgrade to npm@2, run: npm WARN deprecated npm WARN deprecated   npm
>   -g install npm@latest-2 npm WARN deprecated npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run: npm WARN deprecated npm
>   WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest npm WARN deprecated npm
>   WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your
>   system, you npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding
>   commands with `sudo`, or if npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them
>   from an Administrator prompt.) npm WARN deprecated npm WARN deprecated
>   If you're running the version of npm bundled with npm WARN deprecated
>   Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS npm WARN
>   deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some
>   small npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm
>   run-script` and npm WARN deprecated semver behavior. npm WARN
>   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description npm WARN
>   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN
>   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
>
> > fibers@1.0.8 install /tmp/bundle-dir/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> >     node build.js || nodejs build.js
>
> make: Entering directory
>   `/tmp/bundle-dir/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
>
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers/src/coroutine.o   CC(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers/src/libcoro/coro.o   SOLINK_MODULE(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers.node   SOLINK_MODULE(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers.node: Finished   COPY Release/fibers.node
>   make: Leaving directory`
>   /tmp/bundle-dir/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
>   Installed in
>   `/tmp/bundle-dir/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node`
>   npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js
>   (wd=/tmp/bundle-dir/bundle/programs/server) ansi-regex@0.2.1
>   node_modules/ansi-regex
>
> ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles
>
> escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 node_modules/escape-string-regexp
>
> chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
>
> has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi
>
> strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi
>
> supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color
>
> eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
>
> type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of
>
> amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine
>
> asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap
>
> underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore
>
> meteor-promise@0.5.1 node_modules/meteor-promise
>
> promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise
>
> source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support
>
> semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver
>
> source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map
>
> fibers@1.0.8 node_modules/fibers  ---> 414728bbc413 Removing
>   intermediate container 7acaef8c64d4 Removing intermediate container
>   eb6f7a698dbf Successfully built 414728bbc413 SECURITY WARNING: You are
>   building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker
>   host. All files and directories added to build context will have
>   '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset
>   permissions for sensitive files and directories.

the next step is to run my meteor image using Docker run

```
docker run -d \
    -e ROOT_URL=http://yourapp.com \
    -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://url \
    -e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://oplog_url \
    -p 8080:80 \
    yourname/app
```

I am using Docker on windows and installed docker tool box. I am not sure what should i use for the parameters ROOT_URL, MONGO_URL,MONGO_OPLOG_URL
I am kind of stuck here on what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

A MeteorD image doesn't contain a MongoDB database like the development version of Meteor does. You need to specify the URL of an external MongoDB database. MONGO_OPLOG_URL is optional, and ROOT_URL can simply be `http://localhost`.

More about Meteor environment variables:
http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables